# CSS Unknown input on a comment

Tags: css, codepen

I am  working on a project on codepen, but I keep getting the same css error on a comment at the beginning.  Keep in mind most of this is not my code, just I saw it and wanted to make it interactive, so I forked it. Here is the link to the pen: https://codepen.io/rjacoby/pen/xXMbeQ?editors=0100

```
/* 60 column grid. */
/* 1u key (standard keysize) = 4 columns */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700");
```

The error happens between lines 1 and 2, or after 3 if I delete the first two.  Also this worked a couple of minutes ago and I haven't changed anything. Here is the error:
`<css input>:21:3: Unknown word`

Comment: Works fine for me. No error.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Is the error you're talking about is the error what I also see in console?

Comment: no, codepen displays it in the editor, under line one, in red

Comment: Here is and image [link](https://i.imgur.com/HYk9Sr6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found my error, a missing colon on line 21.  Just a simple syntax error, but I could not find it for some reason earlier.  Taking a break helped.